# IDistributedCache and Session State

Tags: asp.net-core

I have my own MySQL implementation of `IDistributedCache` and using it with `HttpContext.Session`. I currently have two separate web apps pointing to the same cache. Of course the cache is global, so both apps can set global cache values, which I could use to set which users are logged in, or not; however, I was wondering if someone knows the proper way to use cache and sessions to allow a user to login with one web app and “sync” that with another. From my research it seems there is no way to sync session states across web apps in .Net Core (perhaps a bad idea anyhow, since we may wish to cancel a local web app session without affecting all others). That leaves coordinating single sign on with the global cache and the user ID. Is this correct?

Comment: Session should not be used for authentication. There are other more secure mechanics provided for that.

Comment: And they support single sign on without the need for a shared cache.

Comment: Like what? I haven't explored much on this in regards to .Net Core.  If you can point me in the right direction it would be great, thanks.

Comment: OpenIdConnect and federated identities would be a good place to start.